# FlatList is not being visible when i set Flex=1 to the top most view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reactive-programming, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList as follows. I was not able to make the content scrollable, so, I have added a style for the view as flex=1.

After I added a style to the view, The FlatList is not visible at all.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                   // style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    onScroll={this.handleScroll}
                    ref='flatlist1'
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.05}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
  <View key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: index % 2 === 0 ? 'white' : '#f1f1f1' }}>      
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                    {item.playername}</Text> 
                           <Text style={styles.text1}>{item.score}</Text>
                           </View>
                    )
                    }
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I found the answer

Instead of giving flex: 1 to the view, 
set a height and give it to the view as
style={{ height }}